# phpmailer with yahoo not working under any setting

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, yahoo-mail

so i have been working with gmail and using php mailer and it was working fine.

i tried to do the same with yahoo mail but it doent seem to work.

i have tried various ports and settings but it isnt working.

here is the code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>PHPMailer - GMail SMTP test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587; //995 and 465 port tried but not working

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';//only ssl tried not working

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "sender@yahoo.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "sender_pass";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('sender_@yahoo.com', 'sender_name');


//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('receiver@yahoo.com', 'receiver_name');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer YMail SMTP test';



$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('phpmailer/examples/contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

$mail->addAttachment('phpmailer/examples/images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

and i get the following error:

```
 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN

SERVER -> CLIENT: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct is tls, you have a spell mistake:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally got phpmailer working with yahoo.

My Findings:

```
* Ports -> Both ssl/465 and tls/587 work with Yahoo. You dont have to 
  worry about that.
* From Address -> Cannot be something arbitrary, just use your 
  yahoo account email here 
* ReplyTo Address -> This too must be a valid yahoo account 
  or you may leave this blank.
```

And ...

for programmatic usage of yahoo with phpmailer, you need to use **another** passwd ( **not the password** that you use to login manually via the web - got this tip from a non stackoverflow site, maybe expert xchange?  ). This password is called the App Password.  You have to generate it from inside your account.

```
Account Info -> Account Settings -> Manage Your App Passwords 
-> Select Other App -> Key in 'AutoMailer' 
or anything you like and generate the passwd - Its a 4 word passwd.
```

Use this passwd in your phpmailer script.
Everything should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The yahoo SMTP host is: **smtp.mail.yahoo.fr**, the port: **465** and **SSL** is required.

So with PHPMailer:

```
    $mail->Host          = "smtp.mail.yahoo.fr, ";
    $mail->Username      = "youryahooadd@yahoo.fr";
    $mail->Password      = "youryahoopw";
    $mail->SMTPSecure    = "ssl";
    $mail->Port          = 465;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body  = "<h1>hello, world!</h1>"

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";      // sets YAHOO as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```